# How does List<T>.IndexOf() perform comparisons on custom objects?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I wrote a class of account objects and hold a static `List<T>` of those account objects. My program loops through each account in the list, performing some work with the account, and then resetting at the top when it reaches the end of the list.

My issue is that I need to be able to reinsert the account into the list after my program finishes working with it, with some updated info added. Can I do this as written below, using the IndexOf() function to check for the object in the static list or will it fail because I added data to it? I don't understand which fields it compares to see if the two objects are the same.

Note: no duplicates are allowed in the list so there is no risk of updating the wrong item

```
public class Account
{
   public string name;
   public string password;
   public string newInfo;
}

public static class Resources
{
   private static List<Account> AccountList = new List<Account>();
   private static int currentAccountIndex = 0;

   public static Account GetNextAccount()
   {
      if (currentAccountIndex > AccountList.Count)
         currentAccountIndex = 0;
      return AccountList[currentAccountIndex++];
   }

   public static void UpdateAccount(Account account)
   {
      int index;
      if ((index = AccountList.IndexOf(account)) >= 0)
         AccountList[index] = account;
   }
}

public class Program
{
   public void PerformWork()
   {
      Account account = Resources.GetNextAccount();
      // Do some work
      account.newInfo = "foo";
      Resources.UpdateAccount(account);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx)? It says "This method determines equality using the default equality comparer EqualityComparer<T>.Default for T, the type of values in the list."

Comment: If you don't care about order once you implement either a custom `IEqualityComparer` or have Account support `IEquateable` you may be better off using a `HashSet` seance you don't have any duplicates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing the accepted answer did not cover is you are supposed to override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` for `IEquatable<T>` to work correctly. Here is the full implementation (based off of [keyboardP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003950/80274))

```
public class Account : IEquatable<Account>
{
    public string name;
    public string password;
    public string newInfo;

    private readonly StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        //This casts the object to null if it is not a Account and calls the other Equals implementation.
        return this.Equals(other as Account);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return comparer.GetHashCode(this.newInfo)
    }

    public bool Equals(Account other)
    {
       //Choose what you want to consider as "equal" between Account objects  
       //for example, assuming newInfo is what you want to consider a match
       //(regardless of case)
       if (other == null) 
             return false;

       return comparer.Equals(this.newInfo, other.newInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - This should be the accepted answer. The `IndexOf` call doesn't use it AFAIK, which is why my code worked, but for general use there's no reason not to.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the accepted answer in case anyone else comes across it

Comment: It seems sufficient to simply override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` as shown above, without implementing `IEquatable<Account>` at all.

Answer (score 14):

Another option is to use [List.FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx), and pass a predicate. That is:

```
if ((index = AccountList.FindIndex(a => a.name == account.name)) >= 0)
    AccountList[index] = account;
```

That way you can search on any arbitrary field or number of fields. This is especially useful if you don't have access to the source code for `Account` to add an overloaded `Equals` method.

Answer (score 10):

Your object should implement the [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface and override the `Equals` method.

```
public class Account : IEquatable<Account>
{
    public string name;
    public string password;
    public string newInfo;

    public bool Equals(Account other)
    {
       //Choose what you want to consider as "equal" between Account objects  
       //for example, assuming newInfo is what you want to consider a match
       //(regardless of case)
       if (other == null) 
             return false;

       return String.Equals(this.newInfo, other.newInfo, 
                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the proper interface is `IEquatable<T>` as that defines the `Equals` method and is used by `IndexOf` in generic collections. `IEqualityComparer<T>` is used by a separate object who's only purpose is to compare two objects of type `T`.

Comment: I really appreciate the example. I'm still new and learning this as a hobby so a technical explanation is much harder to visualize than the code.

Comment: You also need to override `GetHashCode()` see the **Notes To Implementers** section of the page for `IEquatable<T>`: "*If you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you should also override the base class implementations of `Object.Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode` so that their behavior is consistent with that of the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method.*"

Comment: @blizz - Scott has added extra information in his answer which is important (not required for the IndexOf case but should be implemented regardless). You can unmark mine as the answer and accept his.

Comment: You don't even have to make it implement `IEquatable<T>`. Just overriding `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode` will do it. In addition, there are dangers to implementing `IEquatable` on a non-sealed class. See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/01/05/inheritance-and-iequatable-do-not-mix/

Comment: @JimMischel - I hadn't come across that before, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5):

If your class properly implements [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), then `IndexOf()` will use your `Equals()` method to test for equality.

Otherwise, `IndexOf()` will use reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Predicate for your class, such as:

```
public class Account
{
  public string name;
  public string password;
  public string newInfo;

  public class IndexOfName
  {
    private string _match = "";

    public IndexOfName()
    {
    }

    public Predicate<Account> Match(string match)
    {
      this._match = match;
      return IsMatch;
    }

    private bool IsMatch(Account matchTo)
    {
      if (matchTo == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
      return matchTo.Equals(this._match);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as follow:

```
Account.IndexOf indexOf = new Account.IndexOf();
int index;
if ((index = AccountList.FindIndex(indexOf.Match("john"))) > 0)
{
  // do something with John
}
if ((index = AccountList.FindIndex(indexOf.Match("jane"))) > 0)
{
  // do something with Jane
}
```

You could even change the IndeOfName class to use a flag to switch between the type of info you are looking for. Ex: name or newInfo.