# How to find an item on a generic List using IEqualityComparer?

Tags: c#, .net, iequalitycomparer

I have a list of type `List<TreeNode<DepFile>>`. I need to check if this list has a `TreeNode<DepFile>` previosuly added. I use `IndexOf` for that purpose. I implement the `Equals` method on `DepFile` type.

This does not work.

**The question is:** How can I tell the list that it uses the Equals method implementented in DepFile data type?

Taking my data type:

```
class DepFile: IEqualityComparer<DepFile>
{
    public string coddep { get; set; }
    public int codtipodep { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(DepFile x, DepFile y)
    {
        return x.coddep == y.coddep
            && x.codtipodep == y.codtipodep;
    }
}
```

I build a litte Tree structure of `T`. The `AddChild` method has to check if element is already in the list and insert or not in the list. The `DepFile` or other data that implements `IEqualitComparer` is stored in `Value` field.

```
class TreeNode<T>
{

    public List<TreeNode<T>> Children { get;set; }
    public T Value { get; set; } // It stores the data itself

    public TreeNode()
    {
        Children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    }

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(TreeNode<T> data)
    {
        TreeNode<T> node = data;
        int index = Children.IndexOf(data);// Which Equals use this IndexOf ????
        if (index != -1)
        {
            node = Children.ElementAt(index);
        }
        else
        {
            data.Parent = this;
            Children.Add(data);
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: `IEquatable<T>`, see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003883/how-does-listt-indexof-perform-comparisons-on-custom-objects).

Comment: ... or/and simply override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode`. `IEqualityComparer` is nice if you use LINQ methods since most have an overload that accept an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. You don't need to change the type itself and you can have different comparers if you want.