# Why does IndexOf sometimes not work for lists (or collections) of records?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Using the C# 9.0 feature records, I ran into the problem that the `IndexOf` method of lists (or collections) of records sometimes doesn't seem to work.

This happens in the following example. `IndexOf(b)` returnes 0 but I mistakenly expected 1:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new Thing("Hello", 100);
    var b = new Thing("Hello", 100);
    
    var things = new List<Thing> { a, b };
    
    Console.WriteLine(things.IndexOf(b));
}

public record Thing (string Name, int Number);
```

So my question was, why does this happen and how can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003883/how-does-listt-indexof-perform-comparisons-on-custom-objects) I learned that the `IndexOf` method uses the `Equals` method to find its match.

In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/records) I leaned that records depend on value equality:

> For records, value equality means that two variables of a record type are equal if the types match and all property and field values match.

So I got an unexpected index in my example because I expected records to depend on reference equality, like classes. But if the variable a has the same type and values as b, `IndexOf(b)` returnes the index of a, not b.

**Possible solutions**

1. Write a custom equality check for records as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326511/custom-equality-check-for-c-sharp-9-records).
2. Ask yourself whether a list of classes would be more appropriate in the first place.
3. Refactor your logic so that it is based on comparison with `ReferenceEquals`

Comment: " I expected records to depend on reference equality, like classes" You can override `Equals` (+`GetHashCode`) also in classes. Records are like classes where `Equals` is overridden to compare all properties' values.

Comment: In some cases you also can make the method in question use a completely unrelated (well, not _completely_ but external to the class definition itself) equality comparison. (`IndexOf` does not have such an overload, though)

Comment: Or use `FindIndex` like this `list.FindIndex(x => x.ReferenceEquals(b))`